# Como saber que CheckBox fueron seleccionados Para poder Actualizar

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Actualmente estoy trabajando sobre una ventana emergente y la tengo de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que esta es la vista de actualización, por lo cual dicho usuario ya ha registrado su información anteriormente, ahora me gustaría saber como le hago para que en mis checkbox me marque todos los que, el selecciono al momento de registrarse. Por el momento no tengo código escrito porque no eh sabido como iniciar.

De esta manera se abre la ventana emergente:

```
function alerta() {
                new $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Actualizacion del Usuario</strong><br><br>', {
                    'source': {'ajax': 'perfil/actualizar.php?nickP=<?php echo "$nick2" ?>'},
                    width: 1000,
                    buttons: false,
                    animation_speed_show: 3000,
                    animation_speed_hide: 3000,
                    'title': 'Actualizar'
                });
            }
```

Y el formulario actualmente se encuentra de esta manera:

```
<body>
        <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "proyecto_terror";

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        $nick2 = $_GET["nickP"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick = '" . $nick2 . "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $datos = array();
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $datos[] = $row;
                ?>


                <div id="alerta" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; ">

                    <form id="formularin" method="POST" action="perfil/Update.php"><center><table  class="formulario"  id="tabla" >
                                <tr>

                                    <td><center><label >Nombre: </label></center></td>
                                <td><input onkeypress="sololetras()" id="nombre" class="cajaTexto" value="<?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?>" name="nombre" type="text"></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><center><label >Nick:</label></center></td>
                                <td><input maxlength="20"  id="nick" class="cajaTexto" value="<?php echo $row["nick"]; ?>" name="nick" type="text"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><center>Cumpleaños: </center></td>
                                <td>
                                    <span style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 10px;"> Dia: </span> <select name="dia" class="selector" id="dia">
                                        <option value="01">1</option>
                                        <option value="02">2</option>
                                        <option value="03">3</option>
                                        <option value="04">4</option>
                                        <option value="05">5</option>
                                        <option value="06">6</option>
                                        <option value="07">7</option>
                                        <option value="08">8</option>
                                        <option value="09">9</option>
                                        <option value="10">10</option>
                                        <option value="11">11</option>
                                        <option value="12">12</option>
                                        <option value="13">13</option>
                                        <option value="14">14</option>
                                        <option value="15">15</option>
                                        <option value="16">16</option>
                                        <option value="17">17</option>
                                        <option value="18">18</option>
                                        <option value="19">19</option>
                                        <option value="20">20</option>
                                        <option value="21">21</option>
                                        <option value="22">22</option>
                                        <option value="23">23</option>
                                        <option value="24">24</option>
                                        <option value="25">25</option>
                                        <option value="26">26</option>
                                        <option value="27">27</option>
                                        <option value="28">28</option>
                                        <option value="29">29</option>
                                        <option value="30">30</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <span style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 10px;"> Mes: </span><select name="mes" class="selector" id="mes">
                                        <option value="01">Enero</option>
                                        <option value="02">Febrero</option>
                                        <option value="03">Marzo</option>
                                        <option value="04">Abril</option>
                                        <option value="05">Mayo</option>
                                        <option value="06">Junio</option>
                                        <option value="07">Julio</option>
                                        <option value="08"> Agosto</option>
                                        <option value="09">Septiembre</option>
                                        <option value="10">Octubre</option>
                                        <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
                                        <option value="12">Diciembre</option>

                                    </select>
                                    <span style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 10px;"> Año: </span><input name="ano" class="spinnerT" id="ano"  TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="1950" MAX="2006" STEP="1" VALUE="2000">
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><center><label >Edad: </label></center></td>
                                <td><input class="spinnerT" value="<?php echo $row["edad"]; ?>" id="edad" name="edad"  TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="10" MAX="66" STEP="1" VALUE="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><center><label >Sexo: </label> </center></td>
                                <td><div class="radio"> 
                                        <?php
                                        if ($row["sexo"] == "hombre") {
                                            ?>
                                            <input type = "radio" name = "sexo" value = "hombre" checked = "checked" id = "hombre">
                                            <label for = "hombre" >Hombre</label>
                                            <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" id="mujer">        
                                        <label for="mujer">Mujer</label>  
                                            <?php
                                        } else {
                                ?>
                                                  <input type = "radio" name = "sexo" value = "hombre"  id = "hombre">
                                            <label for = "hombre" >Hombre</label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" checked = "checked" id="mujer">        
                                        <label for="mujer">Mujer</label>                  
<?php
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                    </div>                      
                                    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><center><label >Intereses: </label></center></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <table >

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>                        <input  value="Asesinos"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  name="checkbox[]"><label for="checkbox1" style="margin-right: 10px;">Asesinos</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Misterios" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"  name="checkbox[]" ><label for="checkbox2" style="margin-right: 30px;">Misterios</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Creppys" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"  name="checkbox[]"  ><label for="checkbox3" style="margin-right: 10px;">Creppys</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Ovnis" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4"  name="checkbox[]"  ><label for="checkbox4" style="margin-right: 35px;">Ovnis</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Enfermedades" type="checkbox" id="checkbox5"  name="checkbox[]"  ><label for="checkbox5" style="margin-right: -10px;">Enfermedades</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Leyendas" type="checkbox" id="checkbox6"  name="checkbox[]" ><label for="checkbox6" style="margin-right: 10px;">Leyendas</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>


                                            <tr>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Fantasmas" type="checkbox" id="checkbox7"  name="checkbox[]"  ><label  for="checkbox7" style="margin-right: -5px;">Fantasmas</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Conspiraciones" type="checkbox" id="checkbox8"  name="checkbox[]"  ><label for="checkbox8" style="margin-right: -13px;">Conspiraciones</label>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>                        <input value="Deep-Web" type="checkbox" id="checkbox9"  name="checkbox[]" ><label for="checkbox9" style="margin-right: 10px;">Deep Web</label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><center><button id="btnsave"  style="margin-right: 20px;text-decoration: none;">Guardar<img src="../Imagenes/images/ICO/Mask 2.ico" style="width:20px;height: 20px;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: 3px;"></button>
                                    <button type="reset" id="btncancelar" >Cancelar<img src="../Imagenes/images/ICO/Jack O Lantern.ico" style="width:20px;height: 20px;margin-top: -1px;float: right;margin-right: 5px;"></button></center></td>

                                </tr>
                            </table></center></form>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?> 
        </div>

    </body>
```

De esta manera se guardan los interés, que en este caso serian los `checkbox`:

```
   if ($_POST['checkbox'] != "") {
        if (is_array($_POST['checkbox'])) {
            while (list($key, $value) = each($_POST['checkbox'])) {
                if ($contador == 0) {
                    $registro1 = $_POST['checkbox'][0];
                    $registro2 = "";
                    $registro3 = "";
                    $registro4 = "";
                    $registro5 = "";
                    $registro6 = "";
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 1) {
                    $registro2 = $_POST['checkbox'][1];
                    $registro3 = "";
                    $registro4 = "";
                    $registro5 = "";
                    $registro6 = "";
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 2) {
                    $registro3 = $_POST['checkbox'][2];
                    $registro4 = "";
                    $registro5 = "";
                    $registro6 = "";
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 3) {
                    $registro4 = $_POST['checkbox'][3];
                    $registro5 = "";
                    $registro6 = "";
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 4) {
                    $registro5 = $_POST['checkbox'][4];
                    $registro6 = "";
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 5) {
                    $registro6 = $_POST['checkbox'][5];
                    $registro7 = "";
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 6) {
                    $registro7 = $_POST['checkbox'][6];
                    $registro8 = "";
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 7) {
                    $registro8 = $_POST['checkbox'][7];
                    $registro9 = "";
                    $contador++;
                } else if ($contador == 8) {
                    $registro9 = $_POST['checkbox'][8];
                }
            }
        }

$cadena = $registro1 . " " . $registro2 . " " . $registro3 . " " . $registro4 . "  " . $registro5 . " " . $registro6 . " " . $registro7 . " " . $registro8 . " " . $registro9;


mysql_query("insert into usuario(nombre,nick,password,fecha_nac,edad,sexo,intereses,fecha_reg) values ('$nombre','$nick','$password','$cumpleano','$edad','$sexo','$cadena','$fechaR')");
```

Y así es como se almacenan en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahorita solo hay un interes, pero si se agregan mas, se van asignando al mismo campo de la bd y se se para con un breve guion

Aquí se mira como aparece en mi `checkbox` las opciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí se puede apreciar los intereses guardados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No hay coincidencia mas que en uno y cuando convierto el `explode` en `imploder` esto me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como hago la función en cada `checkbox`:

```
<tr>
    <td><center><label >Edad: </label></center></td>
    <td><input class="spinnerT" value="<?php echo $row["edad"]; ?>" id="edad" name="edad"  TYPE="NUMBER" MIN="10" MAX="66" STEP="1" VALUE="20"></td
</tr>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se rellenan Los otros datos de la ventana?¿de dónde salen?

Comment: el nombre y el nick son textfield y es fácil de traer la información en ese elemento, el cumpleaños es en comboBox la edad es en un spinner, el sexo es en radioBautton. y los datos salen de una tabla llamada usuarios en mi base de datos

Comment: ¿Y cómo se abre la ventana emergente? Cómo se rellenen los checkboxes va a depender mucho de dónde esté la información (¿se pasa a la página de algún modo?) y de cómo se abra la ventana emergente. Falta información clave para saber cómo afrontar el problema.

Comment: ya puedo rellenar todos los demás elementos, excepto los checkBox, pero actualizare mi post con el código que me falta

Comment: gracias! Voy a verlo

Comment: ¿Dónde y cómo se guardan los intereses? Dependiendo de cómo se guarden en la base de datos y de si los tienes en el `$row` entonces podrás marcar las casillas o no dependiendo de su valor

Comment: Aparte y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, el código de arriba puede sufrir ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar consultas preparadas en lugar de crear las sentencias SQL de manera dinámica.

Comment: si gracias por la recomendación, esta pagina no sera visible, por eso no le pongo empeño en la parte de seguridad tal vez después haga una pagina especifica para aprender la seguridad en la web. por cierto eh modificado el post para que observes la nueva información, perdón si no soy tan preciso es que apenas estoy iniciando y no se lo que otros necesitan para resolver este problema. gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: OK. Ya veo como está en el código y como se guarda y se lee en `$row["intereses"]`. Voy a preparar una respuesta

Comment: No asumas que por no ser visible al mundo exterior no tendrás ataques, desde una intranet o incluso red local si no validas entradas, te encontrarás sorpresas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de las últimas actualizaciones, puedo ver que la tabla contiene un campo "intereses", con lo cual el interés o intereses seleccionados estará en la variable `$row["intereses"]`. Entonces lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Crear una nueva variable que será un array creado a partir de `$row["intereses"]` (separando por `,` usando [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php))
2. Cuando se llegue al checkbox:

   1. Comprobar si el valor está en el array creado en el punto 1 (con [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)).
   2. Si lo está, marcar la casilla

El código que se añadiría a cada checkbox sería:

```
<?php if (array_search( [VALOR_DEL_CHECKBOX], $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?>
```

Esto sería algo así (sólo pongo la parte relevante y ojo porque no lo he podido probar, puede contener algún fallo):

```
<?php

$intereses = explode(",", $row["intereses"]);
?>

<tr>
  <td><input  value="Asesinos"  type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"  name="checkbox[]" <?php if (array_search("Asesinos", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?>><label for="checkbox1" style="margin-right: 10px;">Asesinos</label>
  </td>
  <td><input value="Misterios" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"  name="checkbox[]" <?php if (array_search("Misterios", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?>><label for="checkbox2" style="margin-right: 30px;">Misterios</label>
  </td>
  <td><input value="Creppys" type="checkbox" id="checkbox3"  name="checkbox[]" <?php if (array_search("Creppys", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?> ><label for="checkbox3" style="margin-right: 10px;">Creppys</label>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input value="Ovnis" type="checkbox" id="checkbox4"  name="checkbox[]"  <?php if (array_search("Ovnis", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?>><label for="checkbox4" style="margin-right: 35px;">Ovnis</label>
  </td>
  <td><input value="Enfermedades" type="checkbox" id="checkbox5"  name="checkbox[]" <?php if (array_search("Enfermedades", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?> ><label for="checkbox5" style="margin-right: -10px;">Enfermedades</label>
  </td>
  <td><input value="Leyendas" type="checkbox" id="checkbox6"  name="checkbox[]" <?php if (array_search("Leyendas", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } ?> ><label for="checkbox6" style="margin-right: 10px;">Leyendas</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya se ha podido seleccionar checkbox por medio del arreglo que se hizo mediante explode, solo que todos se seleccionan sea cual sea su valor, queria preguntarte de donde tomas este valor.

<?php if (array_search("Misterios", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; }

"Misterios", es que esa opción no la seleccione y me la marca como checkeada, gracias de antemanos

Comment: ¿Esa es la única que te marca como chequeada y no lo está? Que raro. ¿Podrías compartir el valor del arreglo (puedes escribirlo por pantalla usando `print_r`)?

Comment: claro que si, solo que lo pondré en la actualización de mi post

Comment: Ya eh modificado mi post, por si gustas observarlo y la impresión la hice en el mismo formulario

Comment: @David Si te fijas, la cadena en tu base de datos no está separada por coma sino por un espacio. Cambia el `explode` para que en lugar de romper por coma rompa por `" "` a ver si así funciona

Comment: No tampoco, de hecho le puse el espacio en blanco y le acabo de agregar las comas entre cada interés y tampoco, sigue checkeando todas, una disculpa es que se me había olvidado que había quitado las comas

Answer (score 0):

El último aporte me sirvió mucho, pero me marca todos excepto el último, a que se puede deber?

```html
$opt = explode(',', $cods);
foreach ($res as $row) {
 $checked = '';
 if (array_search($row->codigo, $opt) > 0) $checked = 'checked';
 $msg .= '<div class="form-check">
 <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="equip_cubierta[]" id="equip_cubierta' . $row->codigo . '" value="' . $row->codigo . '" ' . $checked . '>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="equip_cubierta' . $row->codigo . '">' . $row->nombre . '</label>
</div>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

En vez de

```
<?php if (array_search("Misterios", $intereses) >= 0) { echo "checked"; } "Misterios"
```

usa

```
<?php if (array_search("Misterios", $intereses) > 0) { echo "checked"; } "Misterios"
```

Es decir, quita el signo `=` porque al tener los no seleccionados valor "0" serán marcados de igual manera.

Comment: Hey bienvenido Diego, crees que tu respuesta aporte una solución?, en realidad ya existe una respuesta aceptada para esta pregunta. Te invito a revisar [answer]. Veo que no has realizado el [tour] , te invito a realizarlo para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio,